# Is there a way to precise average price of house or apartment by city using schema.org?

Tags: schema.org, microdata, ldjson

I am trying to set up a schema.org in order to indicate Google the average price of real estate in a specific area.
I have thousands of urls. Each one is dealing with real estate prices in a specific city.
I have already set up a schema.org for dataset.

```
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Dataset",
    "name": "L'Apporteur d'Immo | Tous les prix de l'immobilier pour Paris 8e Arrondissement",
    "description": "Ensemble de statistiques immobilières fournies par l'Apporteur d'Immo, spécialiste des prix immobiliers partout en France Métropolitaine et des estimations immobilières en ligne. Découvrez les prix immobiliers par quartier, commune, rue ...",
    "url": "https://www.lapporteurdimmo.com/prix-immobilier/commune-75008-75108-Paris-8eme-arrondissement",
    "isBasedOn": {
        "@type": "CreativeWork",
        "schema:name": "Carte des prix immobiliers",
        "schema:publisher": "L'Apporteur d'Immo | Spécialiste des prix immobiliers et estimation en ligne",
        "schema:url": "https://www.lapporteurdimmo.com/"
    },
    "license" : "https://www.lapporteurdimmo.com/",
    "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "lastReviewed": "20210404"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "prix immobilier paris 8",
        "prix m2 paris 8",
        "Immobilier Paris 8",
        "Immobilier 75008"
        ],
    "creator": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "url": "https://www.lapporteurdimmo.com",
        "name": "L'Apporteur d'Immo | Spécialiste des prix immobiliers et estimation en ligne",
        "contactPoint": {
            "@type": "ContactPoint",
            "contactType": "customer service",
            "email": "contact@lapporteurdimmo.com",
            "url": "https://www.lapporteurdimmo.com"
        }
    },
    "includedInDataCatalog": {
        "@type": "DataCatalog",
        "name": "L'Apporteur d'Immo | Spécialiste des prix immobiliers et estimation en ligne",
        "url": "https://www.lapporteurdimmo.com"
    },
    "distribution": [
        {
            "@type": "DataDownload",
            "encodingFormat": "text/html",
            "contentUrl": "https://www.lapporteurdimmo.com/prix-immobilier/commune-75008-75108-Paris-8eme-arrondissement"
        }
    ],
    "temporalCoverage": "2014-01-01/2021-04-04",
    "spatialCoverage": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "name": "Paris 8e Arrondissement",
        "geo": {
            "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
            "latitude": 48.8719638,
            "longitude": 2.3115598
        },
        "address": {
            "@type": "PostalAddress",
            "addressCountry": "FR",
            "addressLocality": "Paris 8e Arrondissement",
            "addressRegion": "Paris",
            "postalCode": "75008"
        }
    },
    "variableMeasured": [
        {
            "@type": "PropertyValue",
            "name": "Prix immobilier maison",
            "value": 10233,
            "unitText": "€"
        },
        {
            "@type": "PropertyValue",
            "name": "Maison- Evolution prix immobilier sur 1 an",
            "value": 0,
            "unitCode": "P1"
        },
        {
            "@type": "PropertyValue",
            "name": "Prix immobilier appartement",
            "value": 12390,
            "unitText": "€"
        },
        {
            "@type": "PropertyValue",
            "name": "Appartement - Evolution prix immobilier sur 1 an",
            "value": 13,
            "unitCode": "P1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I would like to do the same regarding the GOOGLE SEARCH. The schema would help Google to understand that the url is dealing with information about an area, then to understand that it is about real estate, than to indicate that is regarding house, then the average price is ...

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You'll need to do something like this: Place/containedIn/GeoSpacialGeometry/geoContains/(DE-9IM)/mainEntityOfPage/CreativeWork/offers/Offer/itemOffered/AggregateOff/price. That concatenated statement links the required `@Type` and `property` to create your graph. One edge and node enables you to express the `price` for your target aggregation - the expression you want to present to Google Search.

Comment: by convention UpperCase is `@Type` and lowerCase is `@property`

Comment: To be honnest, I am a novice on it and do not really understand. Is it possible to provide a json-ld structure to help me with an example?